# How to intergrate PayPal Multiparty for a marketplace platform with Onboarding seller, ....?

Tags: paypal, integration, payment-gateway, marketplace

I am doing a project creating a marketplace platform between sellers and buyers. Now Im trying to integrate a payment method for buyers to pay to the sellers and PayPal Multiparty come up. For my understanding, each sellers will onboard their PayPal account with my platform, so I can have their PayPal information to transfer the money to them. Then I create a PayPal payment gateway so that whenever a buyer buys a product, they will sign in with their PayPal account and transfer the money. But that is all I understand, I dont know if the buyers will send the money to my platform and then I send to the sellers, or the buyers will send directly to the sellers, and how to implement it?? Can someone give me an explaination and guidance. It will be very helpful for me (and I just want to integrate on the sandbox level)
This is the document of PayPal Multiparty: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/multiparty/

Answer (score 0):

Multiparty transactions go directly from the payer to the seller. They are normal PayPal transactions in that sense, with some other features available as explained in the documentation.

The rest of your question (how to implement, etc) is too general. Follow the documentation and see what you come up with, but note that for live/production the API caller must be an approved PayPal partner.